# Object drag not moving at the same rate as the pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop system but I'm having a problem with the drag rate at the moment. Currently when I drag an object it only moves a tiny fraction of the amount that my pointer actually moves. How do I fix this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DragHandling : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public float partScale;

    [HideInInspector] public Transform placeholderParent = null;
    [HideInInspector] public Transform parentToReturnTo = null;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject trashCan; 
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject partsPanel;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject partsWindow;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject buildBoard;

    GameObject placeholder = null;
    GameObject dragLayer;
    Vector3 buildPanelScale;
    Vector3 partsPanelScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector3 startPosition;

    private Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;

    void Start ()
    {
        dragLayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DragLayer");
        buildBoard = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board");
        partsPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Parts");
        partsWindow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PartsWindow");
        trashCan = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Trash");
    }

    #region IPointerClickHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
            transform.SetAsLastSibling();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IBeginDragHandler implementation

    public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        worldPos.z = transform.position.z;
        offset = worldPos - transform.position;

        // create placeholder gap and hold correct position in layout
        placeholder = new GameObject();
        placeholder.transform.SetParent(transform.parent);
        placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(transform.GetSiblingIndex());
        parentToReturnTo = transform.parent;                                    // store original parent location
        placeholderParent = parentToReturnTo;                                   // set placeholder gameobject transform
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;                     // turn off image raycasting when dragging image in order to see what's behind the image            
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDragHandler implementation

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        worldPos.z = transform.position.z;
        worldPos = worldPos - offset;
        transform.position = worldPos;

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);                                       // pop object to draglayer to move object out of parts Panel
        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEndDragHandler implementation

    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        offset = Vector3.zero;

        transform.SetParent(parentToReturnTo);                                  // Snaps object back to orginal parent if dropped outside of a dropzone
        transform.SetSiblingIndex(placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex());     // Returns card back to placeholder location
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;                      // turn Raycast back on
        Destroy(placeholder);                                                   // kill the placeholder if object hits a drop zone or returns to parts panel

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
        {
            buildPanelScale = new Vector3(partScale, partScale, partScale);
            transform.localScale = buildPanelScale;
            transform.SetAsLastSibling();                                       // always place last piece on top
        }
        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
            transform.localScale = partsPanelScale;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right off the back, you should use `eventData.position` instead of `Input.mousePosition`. `ScreenToWorldPoint` takes a `Vector3` but `Input.mousePosition` is a `Vector2`. I also personally wouldn't use `ScreenToWorldPoint` for this purpose, id use a raycast, and use the `RayCastHit hit.point` for where to put the object as its being dragged, which would be alot more accurate for you.

Actually, since you are using Unity Canvas, you should use `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(...)` and put in the parent rect or canvas for what you are trying to drag. It will give you the coordinates you want.

implementation:

```
RectTransform parentRect = (RectTransform)objectToBeDragged.transform.parent;
Vector2 posInParent;
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentRect, eventData.position, Camera.main, out posInParent);

objectToBeDragged.localPosition = posInParent;
```

I also just realized another problem you might be experiencing is that you are using `transform.position` instead of `transform.localPosition` not saying for sure thats the problem but sometimes that can really bite you in the ass.

Comment: Hi @Andrew - How exactly would I implement `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(...) `? I'm not familiar with that class.

Comment: So if I'm dropping this class into each object to than the objectToBeDragged would be itself, correct? I'm afraid I'm still having trouble integrating this into my code. When I drag the object jumps to the center of the screen OnEndDrag. Would it be possible to show me how to tie this together?

Comment: You only need 1 instance of this script, `objectToBeDragged` could be the object registered that you have clicked on in `OnBeginDrag`, if no object is found, you dont have to continue initiating the `OnDrag` calls. Unfortunately i cannot dedicate much time to helping you integrate this code, but i will say it is very simple once you get the point of it all. You will have to change your `OnBeginDrag`, `OnDrag`, and `OnEndDrag` accordingly. use the Unity API http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll keep at it!